# Best practice for shutting down a StatelessService instance on Service Fabric from within itself

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm working on a ServiceFabric scenario where I spawn an instance of a Stateless Service in order to run some tasks. I'm using **FabricClient.ServiceManager.CreateServiceAsync** to create the instance and this works as expected.

Once my tasks are complete I want the service that I spawned to shut its self down so I use **FabricClient.ServiceManager.DeleteServiceAsync**.

The service shuts down as expected, however my debugger stops in the **Program.Main** class at this line:

```
// Prevents this host process from terminating so services keep running.
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

There is no exception, and I am able to hit continue and my application runs as expected after this occurs. But I must be missing a step in order to shut down my service properly. Is there a "Best Practices" way to do this?

I thought about having my service request another service (like a custodian) to handle the shut down, but that seems like too much overhead to me.

My preference would be that the service itself should be able to handle that on it's own, unless of course it turns out to be a bad practice.

**UPDATE:**

I moved the deletion of the service to a ManagerService to handle shutting it down, but my debugger still stops on **Program.Main** of the deleted service as it did before. I also added a screenshot (below).

If I hit continue everything keeps running as it should. Is this because the debugger is still attached and doesn't understand that the service is no longer running under fabric? Can this be ignored and released into production?

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I'm getting a lot of feedback that since I have the debugger running it is expected behavior that it would hiccup once I have no instances of that particular service running on fabric anymore. Since I am getting the same behavior if I delete the service from within itself or from an external service I wanted to get some thoughts on best practices for this scenario...

Ideally having the service clean itself up is best since there are no dependencies to an outside service, it's less complex and there is much less code to write (and less to go wrong).

Surely there is a best practice for doing this outside of having to call **FabricClient**? Is there a "Shutdown" override of some sort? Does the **CancellationToken** come into play here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe is expected (your debugger if you started it in main is probably sitting on that timeout line the whole time). The lifecycle of the host process is not the same as the lifecycle of the services hosted inside it.

When the host process is empty, Service Fabric waits a bit before shutting it down since service hosts aren't normally empty in production and its trying to avoid the overhead of creating and destroying the process (which would slow down subsequent service creations).

By default Service Fabric checks to see if the process is empty about every minute and then will mark it for closure, then makes a sweep and closes empty processes every 10 minutes or so, so you could see an empty process persist for about 11 minutes if you hit the timing just right.

Comment: Thanks masnider - that was what I assumed. It's good to hear from someone on the SF team about it!

Comment: @masnider Does SF signal the process to exit after it has been empty for a while or does it just kill it?

Answer (score 0):

You create your service from the outside. It makes sense to delete the service from the outside as well. Personally, I would send a message to the "custodian" to indicate that service is completed and can be removed.

Comment: I'll try this and see if this does not cause the debugger to hiccup when running locally.

Comment: I'm still getting a hiccup with the debugger. Can I safely assume this is happening because the attached debugger does not release the service? Can this be ignored in production? Updated with screenshot.

Comment: Could you share you spike on GH?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happened to me while working debugging the service fabric. Usually, I see this behavior when my debugger is attached for a long time. As long as the service is shut down and you can verify that it does not exist anymore after `DeleteServiceAsync` is completed, using Service Fabric Explorer site, it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, everything appears fine inside Service Fabric Explorer. The Service is closed as expected and the remaining services run as expected.

Comment: That means, you don't have any instances of the stateless service spawned up, right? The next time you have an instance is when your external call creates the service and do some job and then once completed, shut down or delete the service. If that's the case, things should be good.

Comment: Correct, I only have one instance running so once it is deleted the debugger is running on a process that no longer exists. I am adding an update to my question to make this more about best practices.

Comment: You might want to check this thread as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563875/service-fabric-how-to-gracefully-fail-an-app